# What does a Ruby string wrapped in _() mean?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking at a Sinatra app for a CAS server for SSO. I'm unsure what the underscore and parentheses mean in the string assignment. Here's a sample line:

```
@message = {:type => 'confirmation', :message => _("You have successfully logged in.")}
```

But it's also used in ERB:

```
<%= _("Username") %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_` is the name of the translation method of [`GetText`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gettext/).

So `_` basically means: Take the following string and use it as a key to find a localized/translated version.